# Adding a subtree (from a JSON source) to a tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to extend `niTree jQuery plugin` to be able to append subtrees from a JSON source to a node (by it's id). Here is the plugin:
https://github.com/AlexLibs/niTree

All the functionality of the tree should be applied to the appended subtree including:

- expand/collapse
- check/uncheck the descendants
- effect on the parents state (including the indeterminate state)

The subtree's JSON may include some settings saying that the node is checked and it may effect the state of the parents when the subtree is appended.

The JSON source for the subtree will have the same format as the one that used to create an niTree itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality was added and committed on GitHub.